# The bug in a simple strategy pattern

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Recently, I'm practicing the strategy pattern in C++. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Isquare {
public:
    virtual void draw()=0;       
};

class circle:public Isquare {
public:
  void draw() {
       cout<<"circle"<<endl;
  }
};

class rectangle:public Isquare {
public:
  void draw(){
       cout<<"rectangle"<<endl;
  }      
};

class graph {
  Isquare* ss;
public:
  graph() {
    ss = 0;     
  } 

  void setGraph(Isquare* Is) {
      ss = Is;      
  }
  void draw(){
      ss->draw();
  }          
};

int main(void) {   
  graph* GG;
  GG->setGraph(new circle);
}
```

That is correct and no bugs in this code.
But I also tried another way to implement it and the code is as below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Isquare {
public:
  virtual void draw()=0;       
};

class circle:public Isquare {
public:
  void draw() {
       cout<<"circle"<<endl;
  }
};

class rectangle:public Isquare {
public:
  void draw(){
      cout<<"rectangle"<<endl;
  }      
};

class graph {
  Isquare* ss;
public:
  graph(){
     ss = 0;     
  } 

  void setGraph(Isquare* Is){
     ss = Is;      
  }   
  void draw(){
     ss->draw();
  }
};

int main(void) {   
  graph* GG;
  circle _circle; 
  GG->setGraph(&_circle);//why it core down???   
}
```

And I got the segmentation fault after I run it....
Why it cases segmentation fault? Thx!

Comment: A debugger will tell you.

Comment: Change `graph* GG;` to `graph GG;` in the main

Comment: Your first code is undefined, just like the second, since `GG` isn't initialised. Before you even start thinking about design patterns, you should learn the fundamentals of the language.

Comment: It is also NOT the strategy pattern as usually implemented in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to create the GG object.

```
 graph* GG;
```

should be

```
 graph* GG = new graph();
```

Comment: `new` is not required if just do `graph GG;`. And so no memory leak.

Comment: Thanks, but why the first version:

  graph* GG;
  GG->setGraph(new circle);


It can be worked without creating a GG object?

Comment: @Ted Actually both are wrong.  Segmentation fault, happens, when a process access the memory which it does not own. Or if a process tries to update memory which is not writable. In you first program, try   graph* GG=NULL; GG->setGraph(new circle); Then it will always crash.

Answer (score 4):

You did not allocate memory for GG